# Where is the signature value read from in this query?

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query, and need to figure out where the "signatures" data is actually being read from. It's not from the 'claims' table, and doesn't seem to be from the 'questionnaire_answers' table. I believe it will be a boolean value, if that helps at all.

I'm reasonably proficient at SQL, but the joins have left me a bit confused.

(There's some PHP, but it's not relevant to the question).

```
$SQL="SELECT surveyor, COUNT(signed_total) AS 'total', SUM(signed_total) AS 'signed_total' FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT claims.claim_id, CONCAT(surveyors.user_first_name, CONCAT(' ', surveyors.user_surname)) AS 'surveyor', CASE WHEN signatures.claim_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'signed_total' FROM claims
    INNER JOIN users surveyors ON claims.surveyor_id = surveyors.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN signatures ON claims.claim_id = signatures.claim_id
    INNER JOIN questionnaire_answers ON questionnaire_answers.claim_id = claims.claim_id
    WHERE (claims.claim_type <> ".$conn->qstr(TYPE_DESKTOP).") 
    AND (claims.claim_type <> ".$conn->qstr(TYPE_AUDIT).") 
    AND (claims.claim_cancelled_id <= 0) 
    AND (claims.date_completed BETWEEN '".UK2USDate($start_date)." 00:00:00' AND '".UK2USDate($end_date)." 23:59:59') 
) AS tmp
GROUP BY surveyor 
ORDER BY surveyor ASC
";
```

Thank you!

Comment: signatures is a table (see `LEFT OUTER JOIN signatures`).

Comment: So it is. I missed it in the 200+ tables that form the system's DB. Mind posting this as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Sometimes it's so easy to earn points :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

signatures is a table (see `LEFT OUTER JOIN signatures` in your query).

Answer (score 1):

As written in `FROM` clause :

```
 FROM claims 
 INNER JOIN users surveyors ON claims.surveyor_id = surveyors.user_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN signatures ON claims.claim_id = signatures.claim_id
```

The LEFT keyword means that the rows of the left table are preserved; So all rows from `claims` table are considered and `NULL` marks are added as placeholders for the attributes from the nonpreserved side of the join which is `signatures` table here.

So `CASE WHEN signatures.claim_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'signed_total'` basically checks that if a match between these two tables exists based on `claim_id` then `signed_total` column should have value 1 else 0.

Hope that helps!!